# SHA 256 in NodeJs

Tags: java, node.js, sha256

I am facing issue implementing this JAVA code in NodeJS

```
        MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
        md.update(val.getBytes());
        byte byteData[] = md.digest();

        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();

        for (int i = 0; i < byteData.length; i++) {
            sb.append(
                Integer.toString(
                    (byteData[i] & 0xff) + 0x100, 16
                ).substring(1)
            );
        }

        return sb.toString();
```

This is not strictly SHA-256. I wouldd like to understand what different is happening here.

I understand the way to generate a SHA-256 in NodeJS is:

`crypto.createHash('sha256').update(message).digest('hex')`

But in this case, it gives me a different result than the JAVA code.

Do I need to get the digest binary and then generate the hex in a way different than what `digest(hex)` does ?

Comment: By doing research and trying things on your own.

Comment: I did try but wasn't able to do the same. `crypto.createHash('sha256').update(message).digest('hex')` should be enough but I am getting different hash.

Comment: Don't you think that would be relevant to your question here? As it is written currently, this question comes off as a request for somebody else to write code for you. I recommend you edit the question to explain your exact issue more clearly.

Comment: thanks @rmlan, I have updated the question.